# Bash script for downloading images

Tags: bash

Please assist to check why the following script doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#Description: Images downloader
#Filename: img_downloader.sh
if [ $# -ne 3 ];
then
echo "Usage: $0 URL -d DIRECTORY"
exit -1
fi
for i in {1..4}
do
case $1 in
-d) shift; directory=$1; shift ;;
*) url=${url:-$1}; shift;;
esac
done
mkdir -p $directory;
baseurl=$(echo $url | egrep -o "https?://[a-z.]+")
curl –s $url | egrep -o "<img src=[^>]*>" | sed 's/<img src=\"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g' > /tmp/$$.list
sed -i "s|^/|$baseurl/|" /tmp/$$.list
cd $directory;
while read filename;
do
curl –s -O "$filename" --silent
done < /tmp/$$.list
```

The result it gives is as follows:

```
bash-3.2$ ./img_downloader.sh https://www.web-statistics.org -d images
./img_downloader.sh: line 1: bash-3.2$: command not found
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: –s
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
sed: 1: "/tmp/1638.list": invalid command code 1
```

Comment: try with `-k` option to curl, or install web-statistic's ssl cert into your ssl cert directory.

Comment: The edit removed `bash-3.2$` from the first line of the script, but the error message looks like it was actually there in the first line of the file, though obviously it should not be.  Could you please follow up with a confirmation, and/or update the question to properly reflect what happens if you remove any such line?

Comment: The warnings you get from http://www.shellcheck.net/ might also be pertinent.  You really should quote your variables properly.

Comment: Some of the erratic behavior suggests that you might have DOS carriage returns in your file.  Can you verify that the line endings are correct, please?  See the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for instructions and more troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then 
  echo "Usage: $0 URL -d DIRECTORY" 
  exit -1 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removed the first line, added -k after curl command, so the result now is as follows:
`bash-3.2$ ./img_downloader.sh https://www.web-statistics.org -d images
+ '[' 3 -ne 3 ']'
+ for i in '{1..4}'
+ case $1 in
+ url=https://www.web-statistics.org
+ shift
+ for i in '{1..4}'
+ case $1 in
+ shift
+ directory=images
+ shift
+ for i in '{1..4}'
+ case $1 in
+ url=https://www.web-statistics.org
+ shift
+ for i in '{1..4}'
+ case $1 in
+ url=https://www.web-statistics.org
+ shift
+ mkdir -p images
++ echo https://www.web-statistics.org
++ egrep -o 'https?://[a-z.]+'
+ baseurl=https://www.web
+ curl -k $'?\200\223s' https://www.web-statistics.org
+ egrep -o '<img src=[^>]*>'
+ sed 's/<img src=\"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: –s
100   389  100   389    0     0     82      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--    92
+ sed -i 's|^/|https://www.web/|' /tmp/863.list
sed: 1: "/tmp/863.list": invalid command code 8
+ cd images
+ read filename
bash-3.2$`